# Receiving this error: The multi-part identifier "c.hrmort" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

All solutions point to the fact that if I've assigned aliases in my code, I should be using them instead of the table name itself. I have assigned alias and I AM trying to use the alias, however, I am still receiving this error.

Does this have to do with using an left join?

My code is as follows:

```
Select 
    x.MrtCategory
    
        from 
            (select case 
            when c.hrmort='CMHC' then 'CMHC'
            when c.hrmort='Genworth' then 'Genworth'
            when c.hrmort=''
                and a.purp in ('P16','P17') 
                and c.tenure in ('Freehold','Condo','Strata')
                and a.secval<1000000
                and a.amorty<=25
                and a.class in ('Standard','Stf Benefit Rate','Stf Member Rate')
                and a.totltov<80
            then 'Conventional Insurable'
            when c.hrmort IS NULL then 'Other'
            else 'Conventional UnInsurable'
            end as MrtCategory,
    sum(a.amount) as 'Amount'

from 
    ODS_WB.dbo.lnap as a left join ODS_WB.dbo.cust as b on a.no_=b.no_ and a.surname=b.surname
    left join ODS_WB.dbo.scur as c on b.rowno=c.rowno_custscur_cust and a.secval=c.secvalue and c.status='active'

where 
    year(a.appdate)=2020 and month(a.appdate)=6 and a.apptype='Mortgage' and a.sourcecode in ('FI',' ')) as x

group by 
    c.hrmort
```

Comment: The error seems quite straightforward. Are you sure the column hrmort is on your `ODS_WB.dbo.scur` table?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: dbo looks more like SQL SERVER than ,mysql

Comment: ok, are you suggesting I tag in 'sql server', I'm fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Your `Group By c.hrmort` is outside of your subquery which is alias'd as `x` and you don't have `hrmort` as a column in your subquery.

Comment: "a" is for "lmap", "b" is for "cust" and "c" is for "scur"? "cust" starts with a c, and there's not a single b in it. Use appropriate aliases for your objects, it makes your code far easier to read. `l`, `c` and `s` respectively would be far better choices. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group by is outside of the subquery, so `c.hrmort` doesn't exist.
Instead group by `x.MrtCategory` and sum the amount outside of the subquery:

```
Select x.MrtCategory,
       sum(x.amount) as Amount
from (
    select
        case 
          when c.hrmort='CMHC' then 'CMHC'
          when c.hrmort='Genworth' then 'Genworth'
          when c.hrmort=''
            and a.purp in ('P16','P17') 
            and c.tenure in ('Freehold','Condo','Strata')
            and a.secval<1000000
            and a.amorty<=25
            and a.class in ('Standard','Stf Benefit Rate','Stf Member Rate')
            and a.totltov<80
            then 'Conventional Insurable'
          when c.hrmort IS NULL then 'Other'
          else 'Conventional UnInsurable'
        end as MrtCategory,
--        sum(a.amount) as 'Amount'
        a.amount
    from      ODS_WB.dbo.lnap as a
    left join ODS_WB.dbo.cust as b on a.no_=b.no_ and a.surname=b.surname
    left join ODS_WB.dbo.scur as c on b.rowno=c.rowno_custscur_cust and a.secval=c.secvalue and c.status='active'
    where year(a.appdate)=2020
    and   month(a.appdate)=6
    and   a.apptype='Mortgage'
    and   a.sourcecode in ('FI',' ')
) as x
--group by c.hrmort -- c doesn't exist outside of the above subquery
group by x.MrtCategory
```

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have an error free query now - I still can't successfully run it as I'm receiving another error "SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'ODS_WB'." but I believe that has to do with access instead of code error, if I'm not wrong

Comment: You can either `grant showplan to <user>` or turn off the `include actual execution plan` in management studio under the Query menu